# Open database connection on every x seconds

Tags: java, database-connection

I am fetching data from database using `ScheduledExecutorService` in java after every 20 seconds.

Currently what I am doing is, I am opening connection in run method and closing the connection at the end of run method of thread.

So is it a good idea to open connection after every 20 seconds in run method and close it or should I use the same connection?

Answer (score 0):

If you feel that the opening and closing is too slow, you can keep the connection open, or better yet use a connection pool to let the pool handle it for you.